# Filling mortar cracks with caulking instead of tuckpointing

Tags: brick, masonry, mortar

I would like to paint some brick walls so I need to fix some cracks in mortar.

[image]

For bigger cracks, I removed the old mortar and tuckpointed but that is a painful, dusty and time consuming job. If I have relatively small cracks, is it possible to use some kind of caulking product (e.g. exterior window/door caulking)?

Comment: It is possible, I would just worry about paint adhesion to caulk, so make sure it is the one you can paint over

Comment: Mortar is intended to be structural. Caulking isn't. I would not consider them interchangable.

Answer (score 4):

They literally sell mortar repair in a caulk tube so consider using that.

[image]

---

I think the comments under your question are hung up on latex/silicone caulk. They are right, it's the wrong product. If you use "caulk" then it will promptly fail because mortar is dusty and granules quickly rip away from it. Caulk would last about 3 months if you're lucky.

Comment: Based on the comment about the job being dusty, I think the OP wants to avoid removing the mortar and just caulk over the smaller cracks before painting.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory It's probably a good thing that I recommended a pre-mixed product.

Comment: Yes but can you apply this over the cracks without taking out the old mortar like the OP seems to want to do or would it only save time on the tuckpointing?